# Can Django return empty form fields one by one?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I want my Django view to return empty Form fields one by one.

The form is a ModelForm inheriting from a single Model.

I haven't tried anything because I don't know how can I make it to return one field instead of all.

I might modify fields of ModelForm Meta class.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare which field you want to work on you form like:

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['pub_date', 'headline', 'content', 'reporter']
```

Then the rest of the fields won't be used.

Comment: How can I make it to dynamically show the empty field of form one by one as user enters data and submits. I think it is something to do in views.py.

Comment: Modify the visibility of the fields in each request

Comment: Yes, I that's what I am into. Your code above is not relevant to my questions. Could you please edit the code and answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can render your empty form's fields as follows:

```
<div id="empty_form">
    <table>
        <tr class="border-0">
        {% for field in form.empty_form.visible_fields %}
            <td class="inline_td">{{field}}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </table>        
</div>
```